# The Java code is not working to create an agent (JADE)

Tags: java, agents-jade

I have this simple java code:

```
public class AnAgent extends Agent 
{
    protected void setup()
    {
         System.out.println("Hello "+getAID().getName()+". I am ready. You?");
    }
}
```

I read https://wrjih.wordpress.com/2008/11/29/running-jade-under-eclipse/ to integrate JADE in Eclipse. I followed every step.

[image]

[image]

but it gives me

[image]

Where is my mistake ? Why did not I see my agent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue Solved**

In the 2nd picture, in `Arguments` tab, you have to write:

```
-gui Agent1:AnAgent
```

instead of

```
-gui jade.Boot Agent1:AnAgent.java
```

Answer (score 0):

the mistake is when you write the agent class is that you only write the agent class where the correct method is to write the full class so suppose you have the agent class AnAgent in the package test you should write the args as follows

```
-gui agent1:test.ِِِِAnAgent
```